# Windows 10 Sign Out Automatically

Tags: windows-10, dell-optiplex

I have an issue that when I login into windows 10, after I put in a username and password, it shows sign in and then automatically signs out without any error message. It has happened since windows 10 updated. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the typical cause is a faulty `NTuser.dat` file.

Solution 1: Is the broken account a domain account, and you try to login on that computer for the first time? Copy your NTuser.dat file from a computer where you logged in before.

Solution 2: You have another login account on that computer:

- You could grant the broken user full admin access, sometimes this works.
- Try to copy the NTuser.dat file from the folder `c:\users\Default` to the broken account's directory under `c:\users`.
- You could run [Microsoft account troubleshooter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13976.how-to-troubleshoot-microsoft-account-issues.aspx) - also see [The Windows Club](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-accounts-troubleshooter).